# Will D&D Adventures have International access?

Tags: dnd-5e, organized-play, dnd-adventurers-league

Wizard of the Coast just announced a [new program for Organizational Play](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/news/adventurersleague).

I'm not aware of how organizational play has worked in the passed other than the Encounters Program when it was for official Gaming stores only.  However in the new release they say there is something special for Dungeon Masters as well as Organizers.  Does this imply that people who don't live in the US will be able to be part of this new Organizational Play, or will it only be for Stores, and Conventions?

Comment: Why ask here? Why not ask Wizards direct??

Comment: @YogoZuno I was unable to understand the corporate speak from the intitial Wizards statement, why would I understand subsequent corporate speak?

Comment: Well, to me, if you have a specific question, asking the entire world is less likely to get a response than asking the people involved with what you are asking about...It would be like asking the whole world to give you advice on what your local grocery store sells, rather than just asking the grocery store clerk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/469150366907396096) between Mike Mearls, the Lead Manager for D&D R&D and others the following issues become clear.

1. At Home DMs will be able to run the same adventures as those being run at stores and conventions. However, they will be slightly modified and will not receive as many of the resources, such as maps, tokens, or most importantly, Magic Item Certificates.
2. Each season will allow you to start from 1st level with a new character, or do a higher level adventure with an old one.
3. All of the perks of being an official Dungeons & Dragons Adventure league will be limited to stores and conventions. (Though in the future [that will include international](https://twitter.com/christulach/statuses/469867515036717057) stores and conventions as well)

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing the various 4e Organised Play programs at a local independent gaming store here in Australia. The support for the last couple of Encounters seasons has been much less than before, but the support was still there in limited form. The support for RPGA/Living Forgotten Realms has been non-existent for at least 12 months. I am told by the store owner that the support for Organised Play will continue under 5e/Next. I have no direct evidence either way, but I see no reason for it not to continue in at least the same vein as before.